# Does this passage of "A Severe Mercy" make a reference to suicide?

Tags: a-severe-mercy, sheldon-vanauken

In his book *A Severe Mercy* Vanauken writes the following:

> If she [Davy] died, I might — since, under God, I must not act to follow her — I might live for years. (pp 158,159).

Is Vanauken making a brief, though cryptic, reference to suicide? Does he realize that such an action, "under God," would be at odds with his faith?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the paragraph from the 2nd page of Chapter VII (The Deathly Snows) of Sheldon Vanauken's 1977 book [A Severe Mercy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Severe_Mercy), about his true love story with his wife Davy, where he was mentally preparing to tell Davy of the grim prognosis of her lethal illness that Dr. Craddock had told him the day before: that she only had 10% chance to recover, and possibly only 6 months more to live.

> Then I was ready to tell her. As I drove in the morning sunshine to Charlottesville, I thought of her offering-up her life for me in the previous autumn. Was this the result? Then I thought with a kind of awe of her belief in July a year ago that she might be going to die, and her asking God then for ‘one more year’ for the sake of the student group; now it was another July—one more year, indeed—and I was on my way to tell her of her death. Any recovery is but a stay of the death that is our common doom: she had had what she asked for. One more year. Was it right for me to ask for more? Was it right for me to ask when she had offered-up her life? How should I approach God? What should I say to the Incarnate God who made the world and suffered it to crucify Him? I thought of *Grey Goose*, never again to sail the waters of this world; I thought of poetry, including my own, and of all dear things; I thought of Islands in the West. Then I rolled it all together into a ball. **If she died, I might—since, under God, I must not act to follow her — I might live for years. Those years and all of beauty they might contain I put into the ball. And then I offered-up all of it to the King:** take all I have ever dreamed, all I may ever long for including the death I shall certainly long for: **I offer it up, oh Christ, for her, for her best good, death or life. This was my offering-up. I asked God to take all, all that was or would ever be, in holy exchange, not for her spared life which would be my good but not perhaps hers, but for her good, whatever it might be.** Later I would pray that she might recover but only if it were for her good. That offering-up was perhaps the most purely holy and purely loving act of my life.
>
> *Source* [A severe mercy](https://archive.org/details/severemercy00vana_0/page/157/mode/2up) from archive.org (Page 158)

You are right, that it was in reference to suicide (which of course would be at odds with his Christian faith).  But he was not considering suicide at all.  Rather "since, under God, I must not act to follow her" was *a brief parenthetical remark* to further show the reader, as a continuation of the narrative of his faith journey, **that his faith had changed the kind of love he had for Davy from pagan love to Christian love**.  In the previous chapter, he explained how Christ had breached the pagan *Shining Barrier* pact he made with Davy before they became Christian, which presumably would have motivated him to suicide.

The rest of the paragraph shows that he was instead contemplating to match Davy's "offering-up her life for [him]" the year before by making a substitutionary sacrificial offering to move God's heart to bring good to Davy, either by God's prolonging her life or something else.  In that sentence he realized that he "might live for years", so the sacrifice was about how during those years he would dedicate the beautiful things he enjoyed to God, which he "rolled it all together into a ball" for the offering.

Comment: @edhuff Saw your question at C.SE but Q was moved here.  You can edit your Q with other Christian angle you are interested in and I'll address them.  One pertinent aspect is the Four Loves radio talks that CS Lewis gave in 1958 shortly after Davy died in 1955 and after his similar experience with his own love with Joy Davidman who also had life threatening disease in March 1957 which led him to marry Joy in hospital.  The chapter on how Eros could be the hardest to distinguish from Agape may well has Davy and Van case as a prime example.

Comment: As I read Severe Mercy a second time, I may have more questions. It's a powerful book. Thanks for being available for future questions. To my embarrassment, I've never read Four Loves — shame on me! I did find A Grief Observed very powerful which I read (again) when m wife had a cancer scare. Again, thank you Grateful!

Comment: @edhuff You're welcome, thanks to your question I become aware of *Severe Mercy* and plan to read it.  If you haven't seen the movie Shadowlands (there are two versions, both good), it's a good background for *A grief observed*. If you prefer reading, there is a [novelization of the movie](https://archive.org/details/shadowlandsnovel00flei) by Leonore Fleischer, which is quite good.

Comment: Love Anthony Hopkins and found Shadowlands very moving. I'll look into the Fleischer piece. Thanks! And enjoy Severe Mercy. A Grace Disguised: How the Soul Grows through Loss (Jerry Sittser) is another one you may want to put on the radar.